# How i can build a drone using ROS2 Humble and Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, ros2-control, drone

I´m very new to the game. Currently I´m trying to simulate a drone with ROS2 Humble and Gazebo 11. I have already build a URDF File and launch file to visualize it in Gazebo. I searched on Youtube and many other Plattforms how i can control the drone in Gazebo with ros2 but i didn´t find any good answer for me. Is it possible to control it via the ros2_control plugin?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* lukaz55, but I'm afraid that questions which ask for a list of tutorials are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Ardupilot is a well-known UAV control platform and there's a tutorial [here](https://github.com/monemati/multiuav-gazebo-simulation?tab=readme-ov-file#run-single-uav). There's a paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.08893) (warning: direct PDF download) that also details using ros2_control (page 5). Please try one of these approaches and, if you're still having trouble, please open a new question that shows what you tried, what you saw, and what you expected to see.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use ros2_control, but there is no ros2_controller available for drones -> you have to [write your own](https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/ros2_controllers/doc/writing_new_controller.html).

But the more challenging task will be to simulate the physics of the drone, lift, drag etc. See for example [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104166/how-does-gazebos-physics-engine-simulate-flight-of-a-drone-or-an-uav) about that topic.

When you just want to override the pose of an object, then you don't need ros2_control or similar.
Maybe you can use `~/set_model_state` from [gazebo classic](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_comm), or other [hints here](https://discuss.ardupilot.org/t/updating-gazebo-models-position-from-sitl/80057).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! For me it would be enough if I could move the drone in the xyz-direction without physical influences. 


Is it easier to use a newer Version of ROS wit the new Gazebo? or will there be some big changes?

Comment: I updated my answer above.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. I may come back for more questions.

Comment: I decided to use ros2_control. However, I can't find any help anywhere on what the script for a drone looks like. Could you help me there?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are looking for now. I included links to the how-to sections above. If you want to learn ros2_control, consult the [demos](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/doc/index.html). But once again, if you just want to set the pose in gazebo, you don't need it.

Comment: I have build a URDF File with a Drone in it. Now i want to control/simulate the drone in gazebo (takeoff, starting propellers move in xyz directions). I do not have any hardware to control in real life, just want to simulate it in gazebo via keyboard or joystick. As you mentioned above i can use the ros2_control plugin but i didnt find any examples in the internet how to do it with a drone. Thank you for your patience